# Как заставить работать скрипт после загрузки изображений?

Tags: javascript, jquery, img

Есть вот такой скрипт. Проблема в том, что он срабатывает до загрузки изображений, хоть и стоит метод .load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slide-img img').load(function(){
    var height = $(this).height();
    var width = $(this).width();
    if (width > height) {
      $(this).attr('style', 'max-height: 100%');
    };
    if (height > width) {
      $(this).attr('style', 'max-width: 100%');
    };
  });
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт срабатывал после загрузки изображений?

Comment: Добавьте html и css ( что бы можно было запустить ваш код)

Comment: Попробуйте этот вариант: $(window).load(function(){})

Comment: тоже не работает(
Можете глянуть тут - https://jsfiddle.net/kino45/jo82d6pw/1/

Answer (score 1):

В упрощенном нативном виде это будет выглядеть так:

```
function loadImage(jq, onload, onerror) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = onload;
  img.onerror = onerror;
  img.src=jq.getAttribute('src');
}

// Usage
loadImage($('.slide-img img'), function(){
  // Do your dirty work
}, function() {
  // Fail
});
```